# What is the actual purpose of display: inline

Tags: html, css

I read about the difference between `display: inline` and `display: inline-block`. This question is not about their difference but about their usage which is very different.

I don't understand why would I ever need to use display inline.

It seems like inline-block can do everything inline can and more. Wouldn't declaring an element with `display: inline-block` without any width, height or vertical margins/padding be the same as declaring the display as inline?

Is there a case where you must use `display : inline` while trying to achieve the same goal with `display: inline-block` won't work?

Comment: To block 'inherited' CSS properties not applicable to inline

Comment: one trivial use case: you have a long sentence and you want to change it's color, you wrap it inside a `<span>` which is an inline element and you change the color. Use inline-block and see how it behave with line break

Comment: @LoveenDyall can you show an example of what you mean?

Comment: and here is another use case where **inline** was mandatory to achieve the result: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53882402/8620333

Comment: See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189810/css-display-inline-vs-inline-block#comment37724106_9189873) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45061654/3233827) for a scenario where it is necessary to use `display: inline;`.

Comment: @YonatanNir notice the use of *long sentence* in my comment

Comment: It's also about semantic . https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element#Inline_text_semantics Should those tags turn into boxes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example from [Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif)'s comment:

```html
<h1>inline</h1>
<p>
This is a sentence. <span style="background-color:red">This is another sentence that's really long and has a lot of words and a lot of clauses and needs to be this way to make the example work so that it breaks to a new line and may or may not be a run-on sentence and is probably long enough now.</span> This is yet another sentence.
</p>

<h1>inline-block</h1>
<p>
This is a sentence. <span style="background-color:red;display:inline-block">This is another sentence that's really long and has a lot of words and a lot of clauses and needs to be this way to make the example work so that it breaks to a new line and may or may not be a run-on sentence and is probably long enough now.</span> This is yet another sentence.
</p>
```

The first one is implicitly `display:inline`, and the second one is `display:inline-block`. Note that the sentence in the span has linebreaks before and after it, whereas the first does not.

Comment: I just tried running this code in my browser and with both cases, they acted exactly the same:  

<p> some text before. <span style="color:red; display:inline-block;"> more words inside. </span> and after text. </p>

Comment: @YonatanNir What browser? The difference is super clear in Chrome, on both desktop and Android.

Comment: OK it seemed like I needed a longer sentence to reproduce it. And the questions with the difference between them don't explain about line breaking of inline-block elements