# Firefox causes `display: inline` before pseudo element to behave incorrectly

Tags: html, css, firefox, pseudo-class

Firefox is causing an issue that does not appear in Chrome, Safari or IE11. When adding the `display: inline` property along with the `::before` pseudo element to a heading element, it causes the `bottom: 0` of the absolute positioned pseudo element to not appear at the bottom of the element but rather at the bottom of the first line.

This only shows on headings that span across multiple lines, does anyone know a work around for this for Firefox? All of the different `display` property values do not make the pseudo element appear the same as the other browsers.

```css
h1 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}

h1::after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 5px;
  content: "";
  background-color: red;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

h1:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:200px;">
<h1>My Heading That Covers Multiple Lines</h1>
</div>
```

CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bXEjGg

Comment: you want to underline a multiline of text with transition?

Comment: Yes, the CodePen in Firefox should look exactly the same as it does in Chrome but for some reason it doesn't. Not sure if it is a Firefox bug?

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo element are tricky when it comes to `inline` element on multiline. In this case, you can consider background to easily do what you want:

```css
h1 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  background: linear-gradient(red, red) bottom left no-repeat;
  background-size: 0 5px;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

h1:hover {
  background-size: 100% 5px;
}

.row {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <h1>My Heading That Covers Multiple Lines</h1>
</div>
```

Related: [How can I achieve a CSS text loading animation over multiple lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53881960/8620333)

---

You can consider [`box-decoration-break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-decoration-break) if you want the same effect on all the lines:

```css
h1 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  background: linear-gradient(red, red) bottom left no-repeat;
  background-size: 0 5px;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
  box-decoration-break: clone; 
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

h1:hover {
  background-size: 100% 5px;
}

.row {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <h1>My Heading That Covers Multiple Lines</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I'm not looking for the same effect on all lines, the underline should only be at last line and the width should only be as far as the last word on that line.

Comment: @TomHartley in this case simply use `ìnline-block` instead of `inline`

Comment: Just ran into this same issue.  It appears the problem has still not been resolved.